# How to add and remove a class when you click on the element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Without using JQUERY I need to be able to change the css class on a div in a table. The following link will show you what the table looks like https://jsfiddle.net/7gwktgxz/

I need to be able to click on a space and it removes the last element of the class, and adds a new one. I need to be able to get the id of the div and change the class of that div (or something similar to that)

**Here is the HTML**

```
<table class="othello-board" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="base white">
            <th colspan="8">
                <div class="base-pieces-wrapper">
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece white"> </div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="game-row">
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-1-1"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-1-2"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-1-3"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-1-4"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-1-5"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece white" id="tile-1-6"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-1-7"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-1-8"> </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="game-row">
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-2-1"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-2-2"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-2-3"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-2-4"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece white" id="tile-2-5"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-2-6"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-2-7"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-2-8"> </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="game-row">
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-3-1"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-3-2"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-3-3"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece white" id="tile-3-4"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece black" id="tile-3-5"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-3-6"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-3-7"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-3-8"> </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="game-row">
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-4-1"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-4-2"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece white" id="tile-4-3"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece white" id="tile-4-4"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece black" id="tile-4-5"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece black" id="tile-4-6"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-4-7"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-4-8"> </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="game-row">
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-5-1"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-5-2"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-5-3"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece black" id="tile-5-4"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece white" id="tile-5-5"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece black" id="tile-5-6"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece black" id="tile-5-7"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-5-8"> </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="game-row">
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-6-1"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-6-2"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-6-3"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-6-4"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-6-5"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece black" id="tile-6-6"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece black" id="tile-6-7"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-6-8"> </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="game-row">
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-7-1"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-7-2"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-7-3"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-7-4"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-7-5"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-7-6"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-7-7"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-7-8"> </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="game-row">
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-8-1"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-8-2"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-8-3"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-8-4"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-8-5"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-8-6"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-8-7"> </div> </td>
            <td> <div class="othello-piece none" id="tile-8-8"> </div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="base black">
            <th colspan="8">
                <div class="base-pieces-wrapper">
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                    <div class="base-piece black"> </div>
                </div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Can't remember if `.attr('class', 'blah')` is js or jquery

Comment: @Coderchu—how many seconds would it take to find out?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the element's [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property:

`document.getElementById('idOfTheDiv').className = "desiredClassName";`

alternatively you can use the element's [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to add or remove classes:

```
document.getElementById('idOfTheDiv').classList.remove('doNotWantThisClass');
document.getElementById('idOfTheDiv').classList.add('desiredClassName');
```

Comment: Or `classList.toggle('classToToggleOnOrOff')`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `replace()` and event delegation. Here is a starting point:

```js
var board = document.getElementById('board');

board.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  if (ev.target.parentNode.id == 'board') {
    var cls = ev.target.getAttribute('class');
    ev.target.setAttribute('class', swap(cls));
  }
});

function swap (cls) {
  return cls.replace(/\b(white|black)\b/, function ($0, $1) {
    return $1 == 'white' ? 'black' : 'white';
  });
}
```

```css
#board { width: 150px; }
.white { background: white; }
.black { background: black; }

.piece { 
  float: left;
  width: 43px; 
  height: 43px; 
  border: 1px solid black; 
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
  <div class="piece white"></div
  ><div class="piece white"></div
  ><div class="piece white"></div
  ><div class="piece white"></div
  ><div class="piece black"></div
  ><div class="piece black"></div
  ><div class="piece black"></div
  ><div class="piece white"></div
  ><div class="piece white"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started, combine this with **Pabs123**'s answer and you should be able to figure it out. Using the [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method and [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), you can add click events to the `div` elements allowing for a a small amount of code to handle a everything.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.othello-piece');
    for(var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
        var div = divs[i];
        div.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e = e || event;
            var elem = e.target;
            var id = elem.id;
            var classes = elem.classList;
            console.log(classes);
        }, false);
    }
};
```

Of course, you probably want to put some checks in there (like if the `divs` variable has `length`, etc) and you can remove the log, that's just showing you it works. Also, [here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7gwktgxz/1/) of it in action.